# Higman's lemma and well-quasi-ordering theory

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

Higman's Lemma is basic to well-quasi-ordering (WQO) theory, but has many specific forms, for example: the Cartesian product of two WQOs is a WQO. Any new extensions?

Usually proved by minimal bad sequence arguments.   Besides Cartesian product Higman (a),
There is Higman (b) re injective order-preserving finite subsequences, and Higman (c)
which says that if Q is a WQO then the finite subsets of Q are WQO by injective order-preserving maps.  There could be further Higman (d) and beyond.

Comment: What is a "WQO"? I think it would help your question if you expanded everything a bit and explained what is what. Also, it is not really clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering

Comment: Please ask again this question in a clearer form.